# Wordpress Captcha not verifying second time after showing error messages in the CF7 form

Tags: wordpress, validation, recaptcha, contact-form-7, custom-theme

Iam using Contact Form 7(V5.2.1) with google captcha in my Wordpress(V5.4.2) website. When i submit the form without filling a mandatory field, the CF7 error is shown and captcha is getting reset. But when i fill the mandatory field and click captcha again, the verification keeps on loading near captcha checkbox. Refer screenshot below. And the form submission stops there as captcha couldn't be verified. Is there anything which i can add to fix this?

[capctcha is not getting verified when form has error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7LPl.png)

Answer (score 0):

i have made some work around in my code, it solved the issue.

Comment: Can you share workaround please?